# Is there any good reason for private methods existence in C# (and OOP in general)?

Tags: c#, oop

I don't mean to troll but I really don't get it. Why would language designers allow private methods instead of some naming convention (see __ in Python) ?
I searched for the answer and usual arguments are:
**a)** To make the implementation cleaner/avoid long vertical list of methods in IDE autocompletion
**b)** To announce to the world which methods are public interface and which may change and are just for implementation purpose
**c)** Readability

Ok so now, all of those could be achieved by naming all private methods with __ prefix or by "private" keyword which doesn't have any implications other than be information for IDE (don't put those in autocompletion) and other programers (don't use it unless you really must). Hell, one could even require unsafe-like keyword to access private methods to really discourage this.
I am asking this because I work with some c# code and I keep changing private methods to public for test purposes as many in-between private methods (like string generators for xml serialization) are very useful for debugging purposes (like writing some part of string to log file etc.).
**So my question is:**
Is there anything which is achieved by access restriction but couldn't be achieved by naming conventions without restricting the access ?

Comment: ...perhaps the real question here should be: how can I more easily test private methods?

Comment: Do the methods need to be tested? Do the methods need to be in this class, or should they be public methods of another class? If you have too many of these types of methods in your class, there's a good chance you're violating the single responsibility principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I don't need to test methods itself by I want to use them for testing other things. For example if there is private method: MakeTempStringForXMLSerialization which is used multiple times to construct final string I may want to access this to log only interesting parts of my objects without using full XML serialization.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz can you make the method internal instead and use `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute to expose them to your unit tester?

Comment: Private methods are easier to code because you have a limited audience - your own class. For example, if the class never passes null to a private method, the private method never has to test for null. And I know I am going to get slammed for this, but I have seen too many instances of the same impossible test propagated down a chain of private methods just so people can say 'I have 100 unit tests written'. If you properly test the public interface, the private methods get all the testing it needs.

Comment: I agree with @BennorMcCarthy. Objects are colaborative, then no probs to call and delegate responsabilities (and it would added more testability to your code). Publicity of Methods is one from many others paradigmas into OO.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple questions/issues that you are raising, so I'll handle each one separately.

### How do I test private methods?

Beyond the [debate/discussion of if you should test private methods](http://www.google.com/search?q=should%20you%20test%20private%20methods), there are a few ways you can do this.

**Refactor**
A broad general answer is that you can refactor the behaviour into a separate testable class which the original class leverages.  This is debatable and not always applicable depending on your design or privileges to do so.

**InternalsVisibleTo**
A common routine is to extract testable logic into a method and mark it as `internal`.  In your assembly properties, you can add an attribute `[InternalsVisibleTo("MyUnitTestingProject")]`.  This will allow you to access the method from your unit testing project while still hiding access to all other assemblies. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

However, given the comments made by you, you are unable to change the structure of source code permanently in your workplace; that you are changing the accessors to test, test, then change them back before committing.  In this case there are two options:

**Partial testing classes**
If you mark the class as `partial`.  Create a second partial class file which will contain your tests (or public wrappers to the private members).  Then when it comes time to merge/commit, just remove your partial classes from the project and remove the `partial` keyword from the main class.  In addition, you can wrap the entire testing code file with `if DEBUG` (or other directive) so it's only available when unit testing and will not affect production/development code.
http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2006/04/14/442836.aspx

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    private string CreateTempString()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

#if DEBUG

public partial class MyClass //in file "MyClass_Accessor.cs"
{
    public string CreateTempString_Accessor()
    {
        return CreateTempString();
    }
}

#endif
```

**Reflection**
You can still access private members via reflection:
    public class Test
    {
        private string PrivateField = "private";
    }

```
Test t = new Test();
var publicFieldInfo = typeof(Test).GetField("PrivateField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Console.WriteLine(publicFieldInfo.GetValue(t)); //outputs "private"
```

Your unit tests could pull out private/hidden data in classes this way.  In fact, Microsoft provides two classes that do exactly this for you: [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [PrivateType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privatetype.aspx)

Given your in-house development process limitations, this is likely your best bet as you'll be able to manage your own tests outside the main project libraries without having to alter anything in the core code.

**Note** that Silverlight (and likely other Core-CLR runtimes) strictly enforce non-public access during reflection, so this option is not applicable in those cases.

So, there are a few ways to test private members, and I'm sure there are a few more clever/not-so-clever methods of doing so lurking out there.

---

### Could all of those benefits could be achieved by naming all private methods with __ prefix or by introducing a private-but-accessible access modifier?

The benefits cited by you (citing others) being:

1. To make the implementation cleaner/avoid long vertical list of
   methods in IDE autocompletion
2. To announce to the world which methods are public interface and
   which may change and are just for implementation purpose
3. Readability

Now you add that these could all be achieved with __ *or* by a change to the language specification and/or IDEs that would support a private-but-accessible access modifier, possibly with some unsafe-like keyword that would discourage this.  I don't think it will be worthwhile going into a debate about *changing* the current features/behaviours of the language and IDE (and possibly it wouldn't be make sense for StackOverflow), so focusing on what *is* available:

**1) Cleaner implementation and intellisense**
The Visual Studio IDE (I can't speak for MonoDevelop) does support hiding members from intellisense when they're marked with the [EditorBrowsableAttribute].  But this only works if the developer enables the option "Hide Advanced Members" in their Visual Studio options.  (note that it will not supress members in the intellisense when you're working within the same assembly)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx

So marking a public member as such makes it behave (intellisense-wise) as internal-ish (no [InternalsVisibleTo] support).  So if you're in the same assembly, or if you do not have the `Hide Advanced Members` enabled, you'll still see a long list of __ members in the intellisense.  Even if you have it hidden from intellisense, it's still fully accessible according to its current access modifier.

**2) Public usage interface/contract**
This assumes that all developers in the C#, and Visual Basic, and F#, and C++.NET and any .NET development world will adopt the same __ naming convention *and* adhere to it as assemblies are compiled and interchanged between developers.  Maybe if you're scripting in IronPython, you can get away with it, or if your company internally adopts this approach.  But generally speaking, it's not going to happen and .NET developers may likely be hestitant to leverage libraries adopting this convention as that is not the general .NET culture.

**3) Readability**
This kind of goes with #2 in that what is "readable" depends on the culture and what developers within that field expect; it is certainly debatable and subjective.  I would wager that the majority of the C# developers find the strict/enforced encapsulation to significantly improve code readability and I'm sure a good chunk of them would find __ used often would detract from that. (as a side, I'm sure it's not uncommon for developers to adopt _ or __ prefixes for private fields and still keep them private)

However, readability and encapsulation in C# goes beyond just public/private accessors.  In C#, there are private, public, protected internal, protected, and internal (am I missing one?) each has their own use and provide different information for developers.  Now I'm not sure how you would go about communicating those accessors only via __. Suggesting single underscore is protected, double underscore is private, *that* would definitely hamper readability.

---

### Is there anything which is achieved by access restriction that couldn't be achieved by naming conventions without restricting the access?

If you're asking *why* did the C# design team go this route, well I guess you'd have to ask Mr. Hejlsberg one day.  I know they were creating a language gleaning the best parts of C/C++ and to strongly focus on the priciples of object-oriented principles.

As to what is achieved by enforcing access via the access modifiers:
More guaranteed proper access by consumers of the API.  If your class utilizes a `MakeTempStringForXMLSerialization` method which stores the string as a class property for serialization, but for performance reasons forgoes costly checks (because you, as a developer have done unit testing to ensure that all of class's fields will be valid via the public API) then a third party does some lovely garbage-in-garbage-out, they'll blame you and/or the vendor for a shoddy library.  Is that fair?  Not necessarily; they put the garbage in, but the reality is many will still blame the vendor.

For new developers attempting to understand how your API works, it helps to simplify their experience.  Yes, developers should read the documentation, but if the public API is intuitive (as it generally should be) and not exposing a boatload of members *that shouldn't be accessed*, then it's far less confusing and less likely they'll accidentally feed garbage into the system.  It will also lower the overhead to get the developers to consume and leverage your API effectively without hassles.  This is especially the case when it comes to any updates you publish of your API in which you wish to change/refactor/improve your internal implementation details.

So from a business perspective, it protects them from liability and bad relations with customers and is more appealing for developers to purchase and invest in it.

Now this can all be the case, as you say, if everyone follows the convention that `__` members should not be accessed outside of the class or provide some `unsafe` marker where you say, "If you do this, and it breaks, it's not my fault!" well then you're not on the same planet as C# .NET development.  The accessors provided by C# provide that `__` convention *but* ensure that *all* developers adhere to it.

One could argue that the restricted access is an illusion as consumers can work around it via reflection (as demonstrated above), and thus there is actually no *programmatic difference* between the access modifiers and __ (or other) notation.  (On Silverlight/Core-CLR, there is, *most definitely* a programmatic difference though!)  But the work developers would go through to access those private fields is the difference between you giving consumers an open door with a sign "don't go in" (that you hope they can read) and a door with a lock that they have to bash down.

So in the end what does it actually provide?  *Standardized, enforced* access to members where as `__` provides *non-standardized, non-enforced* access to members.  In addition, `__` lacks the range of description that the varieties of available access modifiers supply.

### Update (January 2nd, 2013)

I know it's been half a year, but I've been reading through the C# language specification and came across this little gem from section [2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx) which states:

> Identifiers containing two consecutive underscore characters (U+005F)
>   are reserved for use by the implementation. For example, an
>   implementation might provide extended keywords that begin with two
>   underscores.

I imagine nothing necessarily *bad* will happen, most likely nothing will break catastrophically if you do. But it's just one more aspect that should be considered when thinking about using double underscores in your code that the specification suggests that you do not.

Comment: The problem is the code is not mine I just do a branch which add some functionality. Now I can't change public/private/internal at will because it will cause pain while merging (and will be rejected anyway). On the other hand if methods were private-but-accessible I could attach my classes providing some functionality and I could provide the code I used for testing (now I need to delete it before merge request as it won't work with main base).
Maybe it's not the best way to do things but those tests could still be useful for other developers.

Comment: Perhaps then you can make a solid case to management or the developers to change their ways. If this question is an issue about internal development processes, I'm not sure what you're expecting to get out of it. `private-but-accessible` seems to be a bit of a contradiction; it's closest concept is `internal`. Given this, perhaps you should ask a question of "how do I test private methods without changing them"? Maybe the most painless way for you is to manage your own `partial` classes and exclude them from the commit. Then you just need to add/remove `partial` to the original class files.

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz I edited/overhauled my answer to better organize the various edits and issues you raised in comments.  Does it answer the question well enough or do you still have pending issues?

Answer (score 4):

The reason private methods exist are to provide [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

This allows you to provide public contracts by which you want your object to interact, yet have your internal logic and state be encapsulated in a way that refactoring would not affect consumers.

For example, you could provide public named properties, yet decide to store state in a Dictionary, similar to what typed DataSets do.

It's not really a "Security" feature (since you always have reflection to override it), but a way to keep public APIs separate from internal implementations.
Nobody should "depend" on your internal and private implementation, they should only depend on your public (or protected) implementation.

Now, regarding unit testing, it is usually undesired to test internal implementations.
One common approach though is to declare it internal and give the test assemblies access, through `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`, as Chris mentioned.

Also, a clear distinction between public, private, and protected are extremely useful with inheritance, in defining what you expect to be overridable and what shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no real point to marking fields or methods private.  It provides an artificial sense of security.  All the code is running inside the same process, presumably written by people with a friendly relationship to each other.  Why do they need access controls to protect the code from each other?  That sounds like a cultural issue to fix.

Documentation provides more information than private/protected/public does, and a good system will have documentation anyway.  Use that to guide your development.  If you mark a method as "private", and a developer calls it anyway, that's a bad developer, and he will ruin your system in some other way eventually.  Fix that developer.

Access controls eventually get in the way of development, and you spend time just making the compiler happy.

Of course, if you are talking strictly about C#, then you should stick to marking methods as private, because other C# developers will expect it.

Answer (score 1):

It hides a lot of internal details, especially for library implementers who may actually want to hide those details.

Keep in mind that there are commercial libraries out there, being sold. They expose only a very limited set of options in their interface to their users and they want all the rest to be well hidden.

If you design a language that doesn't give this option, you're making a language that will be used almost exclusively for open-source projects (or mostly for scripting).
I don't know much about Python though, would be interesting to know if there are commercial closed-source libraries written in python.

The reasons you mentioned are good enough too.

Comment: "Private" scope shouldn't used as a security mechanism. Declaring a private constant to hide a key is totally unsafe. If not try Reflector or ILSpy. Scopes are to aid and guide implementation, and provide encapsulation for better design, especially useful for library APIs.

Comment: Most obfuscators will automatically pick up on private members and obfuscate them while keeping publically accessible members intact for consumers.  So in that sense, it helps for security, sort of.  If only as a convenience feature when setting up the obfuscator. :)

Comment: The obfuscator could use a naming convention just as well; I understand the point of private methods, I am saying that naming convention without access restriction would fulfill all the purposes and add some bonus possibilities. I am wondering if I am missing something on this one.

Comment: @Pablo True for C# and Java, but this is not a matter of decompilation/reverse-engineering. Nothing, no implementation details can be hidden from that. In any language. Still, the availability of "private" - and probably "internal" - gives commercial library implementors a certain peace of mind. A manager without much programming background aproves a language to be used based on these things (this is based on experience) and language designers want to address those managers...

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz, you can still achieve what you want by marking everything public and using `__` notation.  But since your company follows a different encapsulation paradigm (private access modifiers) you must follow that.  The private access isn't about shielding or protected proprietary content, it's about easing development (debatable, obviously), and easing consumption of the API by other developers.  In some C# platforms, notably the core-CLR/Silverlight, this is even enforced against reflection, so there's that difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're publishing a library with public members, it's possible for users to use these members. You can use naming conventions to tell them they shouldn't, but some people will.

If your "internal" members are public, it becomes impossible for you to guarantee compatibility with the old version of the library, unless you keep all of the internal structure the same and make only very minor changes. That means that every program using your library must use the version it was compiled against (and will most likely do this by shipping its own version, rather than using a shared system version).

This becomes a problem when your library has a security update. At best, all programs are using different shared versions, and you have to backport the security update to every version that's in the wild. More likely, every program ships its own version and simply will not get the update unless that program's author does it.

If you design your public API carefully, with private members for the things you might change, you can keep breaking changes to a minimum. Then all programs/libraries can use the latest version of your library, even if they were compiled for an earlier one, and they can benefit from the updates.

Answer (score 0):

This can lead to some interesting debate.  A main reason for marking private methods (and member variables) is to enforce information hiding.  External code shouldn't know or care about how your class works.  You should be free to change your impl without breaking other things.  This is well established software practice.

However in real life, private methods can get in the way of testing and unforeseen changes that need to occur.  Python has a belief "we're all consenting adults" and discourages private methods.  So, sometimes I'll just use naming conventions and/or comment "not intended for public use".  It's another one of those OO-theory vs. reality issues.