# Do non-existing private variables make python less secure than C#?

Tags: c#, python, security

I am currently learning C# in a course and came across a discussion point due to me having python background. Regarding that discussion I came upon the question: **How secure is python compared to C#?**

So I know that in python there's the convention of "We're all responsible users" and that no class, variable or method is technically really private, unlike in C# where you have the functionality to make public, protected and private instances.

If I write this in C#:

```cs
// File: Circle.cs
public class Circle() {
    private int _Radius;
    public int Radius { get => _Radius; set => _Radius = value}

    public Circle(int r) 
    { 
        Radius = r;
    }
}

// File: Program.cs
public static void Main() {
    Circle c1 = new Circle(1);
    c1.Radius = 2; // Possible, Radius is 2
    c1._Radius = 3; // Not possible outside of Circle.cs -> Compilation error
}
```

It would *sort of* compare to this in Python:

```py
# File: circle.py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.__Radius = radius
    def __getR(self):
        return self.__Radius
    def __setR(self, radius):
        self.__Radius = radius
    r = property(__getR, __setR)
# File: main.py
from circle import Circle
c1 = Circle(1)
c1.r = 2 # Radius is set to 2
c1.__Radius = 3 # Radius is still 2
c1._Circle__Radius = 4 # Radius is 4
```

The above serves as a demonstration of the functional differences of Python and C#.

My question is: *Does the lack of actual private variables make python less secure compared to C#?*

After all. If I would write a cryptographic library of some sort, it would make sense to program that in C# out of pure security concerns, wouldn't it? I wouldn't be able (to my knowledge) to hinder anyone abusing the private variables I provide in said library when programmed in python, whereas in C# I can create a library which does not give access to internally used private variables when used in another program.

**If I would program said library in python, would that library be any less secure than the C# one?**

I'm neither against python nor against C#, I'm simply curious from an enthusiasts standpoint why C# just seems more secure with it's private instances whereas python plays the "be responsible" card and leaves it out *almost* entirely.

While researching about this, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337110/is-there-any-good-reason-for-private-methods-existence-in-c-sharp-and-oop-in-ge?rq=1), in which "Reflection" is explained a little. Reflection

I am not referring to unit testing in this question, where you could assume that you have access to the source code anyways and could just change the property to public.

To elaborate:

If you have a compiled library A in C# and you have a compiled library B in Python, how do these 2 compare in terms of security or privacy when trying to access the private data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member accessibility is not a security feature.  It's a tool to aid programmers by helping programmers understand how a given member is intended to be used by its author.  If someone is in a position of being able to run privileged code on a machine then there *are* no language features to prevent them from accessing the data.  You can make it harder, you can make it *inconvenient* to access the data in question.  But you can't prevent it.

If a programmer is using a library of yours then there is nothing you can do to stop them from accessing and changing any of the "private" data in your code.  If they're doing so then they're simply doing so with the knowledge that they can no longer rely on your code to work correctly.  It's the morale equivalent of taking apart something you bought, tinkering with it, and then putting it back together again.  You might break something if you do it wrong, and (most things) aren't designed to have you do this, but they can't stop you from doing it.

If you're writing code, and need the private data it's storing to be inaccessible to your end users, then you can't let them run it on their machines.  You need to have them make a request to your server, run your sensitive code, keeping all of the information you don't want them to have access to entirely on your own private server, and then sending them a response with whatever resulting information you want them to be able to have.

This is, with very few exceptions, true of all languages.

Comment: So technically, when having a compiled library in C# it's just as easy or hard to get data out of it as in python, is that correct? Adding to that, if I had a Server running the code in either C# or Python, if someone were to get server-access, how accessible would the private members actually be? Is there a difference in terms of accessibility or security in such a scenario?

Comment: @HackXIt It's just as *possible*.  It may be more or less *convenient*.  Not having code in Python, I couldn't comment on which is easier.  It's always possible in either case, or with any other language you write code in.  After all, you can always use the operating system to look at the actual memory, and look at the value where that data is stored, even if the language doesn't expose any means of accessing the value (although pretty much any general purpose programming language does expose ways of accessing private fields).

Comment: Well I suppose that is the case, there will always be the possibility of in the end getting access in all languages. But to me it seems like when writing something in python you're handing out the security anyways, whereas in C# there at least seems to be some sort of fence you need to hop over first.

Comment: @HackXIt It's like putting up a no trespassing sign.  It's doing nothing to actually stop anyone from doing what you don't want them to do, it's merely telling them that you don't want them to do it, so they *know* they're doing something they shouldn't.  It's not a security mechanism, it's merely documentation to users of your code on how you *want* them to use it.  Not how they *can* use it.

Comment: Alright! I think I understand the concept better now and I shouldn't see it as a security feature but rather a documentation format. Thanks!